# Setting a button infront of another view

Tags: android, camera, android-framelayout

I Created a custom Camera app that captures image and stores the image in gallery. My app works perfectly fine, but i have small issues with the view.

Presently My App looks like this

[image]

When I use the Button inside the FrameLayout and set it to Foreground I get a Crash. I have posted the coding below

My MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageHandler preview;
    Camera camera;
    int cameraID, currentCamera;
    Button capture;
    FrameLayout imageLayout;
    SurfaceView imgl;
    private static final String TAG = "CallCamera";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
         * Invoking Camera and Setting the ImageHandler for preview
         */
        camera = getCameraInstance();
        preview = new ImageHandler(this, camera);

        /*
         * Getting the ID of the FrameLayout that displays the camera
         */

        imageLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_layout);
        imageLayout.addView(preview);

        /*
         * Getting the ID of capture Button and setting its Functionality
         */

        capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);

        capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(null, null, null, pic);
            }
        });

    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera cam = null;
        try {
            cam = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return cam;
    }

    PictureCallback pic = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFileDir = getDir();

            if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Can't create directory to save image.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

            String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + photoFile;

            File pictureFile = new File(filename);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "New Image saved:" + photoFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            } catch (Exception error) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "File" + filename + "not saved: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Image could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



            camera.startPreview();
        }

        private File getDir() {
            File sdDir = Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            return new File(sdDir, "MYCAMERA");
        }

    };


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (camera == null) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        }
    }

}
```

My ImageHandler.class(Preview)

```
public class ImageHandler extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Camera imgCamera;
    List<Size> imgSupportedPreviewSizes;

    public ImageHandler(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.imgCamera = camera;
        this.holder = this.getHolder();
        this.holder.addCallback(this);
        this.holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            imgCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            imgCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            imgCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            imgCamera.startPreview();
            imgCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        imgCamera.stopPreview();
        imgCamera.release();
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        imgCamera = camera;
        if (imgCamera != null) {
            imgSupportedPreviewSizes = imgCamera.getParameters()
                    .getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

}
```

My Working activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Capture" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >



    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Changed/Edited XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:foreground="@+id/cameraButton" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="Capture" />



    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Logcat Crash

```
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camera/com.example.camera.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:317)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at com.example.camera.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    ... 11 more
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    ... 24 more
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f080001}
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2239)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:109)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
12-05 11:19:59.346: E/AndroidRuntime(21506):    ... 27 more
```

My Edited XML Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/preview_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The part where i call the surface view

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
/*
 * Invoking Camera and Setting the ImageHandler for preview
 */
camera = getCameraInstance();
preview = new ImageHandler(this, camera);

/*
 * Getting the ID of the FrameLayout that displays the camera
 */

imageLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_layout);
imageLayout.addView(preview);

/*
 * Getting the ID of capture Button and setting its Functionality
 */
```

My new image

[image]

Comment: yes i want to plasce the button on top of the surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_layout"
        .....
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:foreground="@+id/cameraButton" >  //<<<<< here
```

Pass Drawable id instead of Button id in `android:foreground` attribute

Answer (score 0):

android:foreground="@+id/cameraButton" is wrong. You should set a drawable to android:foreground

Comment: Yes I understood that but is there a possibility for me to set the Button on top of the Surface View

Comment: thanks @Shashika for replying, when I try and implement the code, the button is not visible at all the button remains in the background

Comment: Make sure you follow the exact order as in my sample code. Note that this is the full layout. Remove the RelativeLayout completely and use the FrameLayout as the parent.

Comment: I used the code given by you and removed my code but still the preview screen is in foreground and the button is in background(not Visible) but when i click near the button region Image gets captured.

Comment: Post your new layout. And the code where you preview the camera on the surfaceview.

Comment: You are adding a view to the FrameLayout here. That's why you can't see the button. imageLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_layout);
imageLayout.addView(preview);

Comment: Can you please help me how to go about this?

Comment: Check this code which displays camera live feed to the SurfaceView. https://pastee.org/bgx3j